# How to add slide animation when showing elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to add animation effect to following code when showing tree items.

I know that jquery has slide functions, and css has "transition", but not sure how to apply these to my code. Any ideas?

```
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function show(){
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("label");
            for(var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {
              elements[i].style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        .label { 
            -webkit-padding-start: 20px;
            display: none; 
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div onclick="show()">1st Row</div>
        <div>
            <div class="label">First</div>
            <div class="label">Second</div>
            <div class="label">Third</div>
        </div>
        <div>2nd Row</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are planning to use `jQuery` then you can use `slideDown` and `slideUp` method to show/hide elements with animation. There is `slideToggle` method which alternatively show/hides the element with animcation. You can modify your `show` method as below

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bH7sm/1/)**

```
    function show(obj){
       var $this = $(obj);//Here obj points to the element clicked

       //Now you have to show/hide the next sibling of the element clicked
       //We will use next() method which gives the next sibling of element
       //And then call slideToggle on it to show/hide alternatively
       $this.next().slideToggle();
    }
```

Change in the markup

```
<div onclick="show(this)">1st Row</div>
```

Comment: Take a look at the demo I have hidden the div initially as you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
function show() {
    $('.label').slideDown();
}
```

This selects all elements with the `.label` class and slides them into view. There is also a `.fadeIn()` function.

Also, you can attach click handlers by selectors (like an id or class):

```
<div>
    <div class="row">1st Row</div>
    <div>
        <div class="label">First</div>
        <div class="label">Second</div>
        <div class="label">Third</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">2nd Row</div>
</div>
```

Notice I removed the `onClick=""` statement and added a class to the row div. Then you can select the element you want to attach the click event to and keep all the code in one place:

```
$('.row').bind('click', function () {
    $(this).next().find('.label').slideToggle();
});
```

This JavaScript above adds a click handler to all elements with the `row` class and toggles the display of all of the elements with the `label` class in the next element.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L34g3/.

Comment: Same question as above for @ShankarSangoli, in this solution the sub-items are showing when page loading. Can I make the initial state to hide, as in my code?

Comment: Same answer as ShankarSangoli, the css is set to not display the sub-items on pageload, check-out the jsfiddle in my post and look at the top right under CSS.